# get string between "-(" and ")-", linux directory

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

i have in a linux directory a lot of files, plain text with some directories, and i want to search in all those files and get the exactly the string between "-(" and ")-" like:

> bbbfb da bg -(fdsd)- fgfjmui -( juju gfdgf b)- fsdf sdfs dsfdlk,kwwk
>   xwpv -(64fsdfds)- fsdfsd -(a)- fsdfsd...

and return:

- fdsd
- juju gfdgf b
- 64fsdfds
- a
  ...

i read for a while, and i found commands like grep, but i tried and i think that command return the exactly string and just one by line:

```
grep -Rn "-(" *
```

i tried also sed command like:

```
sed -e 's/.*-(\([^"]*\))-.*/\1/'
```

which return all the lines and where is the pattern, only the string inside -( and )-, but is not quite right yet.

i read about awk, but my question is: is possible with grep, sed or awk? there some more things to put on sed command? (i'm kinda new on this)
there is another command to do this? or the other idea i was thinking is make a little c program to read files char by char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep -RPo '(?<=-\()[^)]*(?=\)-)' yourDir
```

this will give you the strings you want **each per line**

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "bbbfb da bg -(fdsd)- fgfjmui -( juju gfdgf b)- fsdf sdfs dsfdlk,kwwk xwpv -(64fsdfds)- fsdfsd -(a)- fsdfsd..."|grep -Po '(?<=-\()[^)]*(?=\)-)'
fdsd
 juju gfdgf b
64fsdfds
a
```

the trick here is "o": from man page of grep:

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/):

```
ack -o -h '(?<-\().*?(?:\)-)'
```

Details of the regex:

```
(?<-\() : lookbehind assertion : dash and opening parenthese
.*? : as few characters as possible
(?:\)-) : lookahead assertion : closing parenthese and dash.
```

If your files don't come use the `-a` switch for unrestricted search. Program options avail in the given link.

Answer (score 1):

Since you suggested using a C program, I figure a perl suggestion might be useful  Using perl gets you access to non-greedy regular expressions/substitutions.

```
STRING='bbbfb da bg -(fdsd)- fgfjmui -( juju gfdgf b)- fsdf sdfs dsfdlk,kwwk xwpv -(64fsdfds)- fsdfsd -(a)- fsdfsd'
echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/.*?-\(//; s/\)-.*?-\(/\n/g; s/\)-.*?$//;'
```

Here's the output for that on my system

```
> ./foo.sh 
fdsd
 juju gfdgf b
64fsdfds
a
```

Comment: Overkill much? `echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*/$1\n/g'`

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle cases where '(' is on its own for some reason (such as in a comment about directory -(dirname)- is in the data).  While your solution does properly parse the given string, I wanted to make sure my solution (or 'overkill' as you state it) was useful in more general applications.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! | sed '/[^-]*-(\([^)]*\))-[^-]*/!d;s//\1\n/g;s/.$//'
bbbfb da bg -(fdsd)- fgfjmui -( juju gfdgf b)- fsdf sdfs dsfdlk,kwwk
xwpv -(64fsdfds)- fsdfsd -(a)- fsdfsd...
!
> bbbfb da bg -(fdsd)- fgfjmui -( juju gfdgf b)- fsdf sdfs dsfdlk,kwwk
> xwpv -(64fsdfds)- fsdfsd -(a)- fsdfsd...
> !
fdsd
 juju gfdgf b
64fsdfds
a
```